# Question about sum over a dynamic list C#

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, language-lawyer

Consider a dynamic list

```
List<dynamic> payments = new List<dynamic>();
```

Add 2 itens to it

```
payments.Add(new { value = Convert.ToDecimal("10,35") });
payments.Add(new { value = Convert.ToDecimal("10,35") });
```

Then sum

```
var k = payments.Sum(x => (decimal)x.value);
var j = payments.Sum(x => x.value);
var l = payments.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.value));
```

The first one works. Second and third don't. Both throw a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" My question is... why ? I wanted to understand a bit better the details regarding the differences between the 3 sum examples and why the first one works while the others don't.

Shorter version of the sample still fails:

```
 (new List<dynamic>(){1m}).Sum(x=>x)
```

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And if you look at generated IL you'll see references to `System.Func<System.Object,System.Int32>..ctor` (which somewhat makes sense as complier need to pick a type for `Func`...)

**TL;DR:** why C# compiler picks `Int32` version of Sum (likely at compile time) for dynamics.

Comment: I'd expect it simply not compile... It's is interesting why C#  pick `IEnumerable<int>.Sum` for `IEnumerable<dynamic>`...

Comment: C# can't infer a compile-time generic type by looking at a runtime type. You could probably fix it by specifying the generic type `var l = payments.Sum<decimal>(x => x.value);`

Comment: @itsme86 but it did for whatever reason pick `int`... instead of failing to compile... (unlike your suggested fix that does fail to compile)

Comment: @itsme86, your suggestion did not work. The syntax you suggested fails to compile.

Comment: Because it is the first overload that matches the signature. See it for yourself: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, could you please explain a bit more about what you mean by C# picking IEnumerable<int>.Sum instead of IEnumerable<dynamic> ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would say it is picking `Enumerable.Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32>)`.

Comment: FWIW, 99.973% of the time, `dynamic` anything is the wrong solution, there are limited use cases where its useful or needed, and usually implemented to make up for a design flaw somewhere else. There are detailed rules for how it tries to choose overload resolution at compile time and the runtime binding, and sometimes counterintuitive leading to many production and runtime problems. However if this is an academic problem, it may be worth while visiting the specs

Comment: @GuruStron indeed... I greatly oversimplify  that in my comment (and cause major confusion for Caio - sorry about that). Indeed it is what I should have said - still no idea why it picks that version at compile time (and Riwen's link to source code does not explain that at all to me at least)

Comment: @Riwen would you mind converting that comment into answer by adding C# spec reasoning for that?

Comment: @CaioSant'Anna I've added shorter sample and some more text - feel free to revert/edit if you think it is not what you are asking. Note that samples 2 and 3 are identical from C# point of view as both `x.value` and `Convert.ToDecimal(x.value)` have type `dynamic` in the context of your question (non-formally - `dynamic` spreads to whole expression if any part of an expression is `dynamic`)

Comment: So the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that all overloads of `Convert.ToDecimal` return a `decimal` and thus it could assume that `Convert.ToDecimal(dynamic)` is either decimal or thows an exception.

Comment: @KlausGütter compiler is smart enough to follow the spec which says it must not try that (as far as I know)...  Plus you can't know all overloads available *at run-time* by looking at types *at compile time* anyway. You can always do exercise of writing your own spec for such operation - explaining how adding an unrelated method with different   return type later will completely change behavior of the code should be interesting (don't forget that `ToDecimal` is just another method to compiler, there is nothing special about it)